# Getting the href attribute from html gives unwanted results

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, electron

I am basically scraping some content off of a website and the HTML looks something like this:

```
<div>
    <a class="title" href="/recipe/pasta">Pasta Recipe</a>
</div>
```

Now after scraping this off of the website I use js to get the href attribute like this:

```
html.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href
```

Now the problem is that this returns: `file:///A:/recipe/pasta` but the result I want is `/recipe/pasta`. Here's a Stack Snippet example of the same problem - the `href` results in the domain being prepended, which is undesirable:

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href);
```

```html
<div>
    <a class="title" href="/recipe/pasta">Pasta Recipe</a>
</div>
```

I can fix this problem with basic string manipulation but that seems rudimentary.

Also `file:///A:` is the drive on my computer the `A:` drive. If I run this on another computer then it will become `file:///C:`, representing the `C:` drive.

It might also help to know that I am doing this on an electron app using nodeJS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getAttribute` instead, to get just the plain value of the attribute and nothing else:

```js
const href = document.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href');
console.log(href);
```

```html
<div>
    <a class="title" href="/recipe/pasta">Pasta Recipe</a>
</div>
```